# Is there anyway to perform a command from the Chrome Commands API from within console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

As the title says, wondering if there is a way I can call a command from the console or using JavaScript.
I'm talking about Ctrl + Shift + P in Chrome DevTools, thought it was called the Commands API but I could be wrong, its got a similar feel to the Command Palette in Sublime Text

Comment: "Built-in actions" is what that palette actually is. No js there.

Comment: @wOxxOm if you want to put that into an answer ill happily accept it.